# Can heroku allow some url to be accessible in its maintenance mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I wonder if I can still allow myself to access things like rails admin, or allow users to access `/help` page when I turn on the maintenance mode in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible; HTTP requests are blocked when your application is in [maintenance mode](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode)